# what are the commands to identify a process stack?

Tags: unix, stack

what commands are there to identify the stack that exists for a particular process?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'identify' ?

Comment: just to read at each step what the process has done

Answer (score 1):

`pstack` will print a stack trace of a running process.

See `man pstack` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gdb`.

```
$ gdb <program> <pid>
gdb> bt
```

Comment: iam unable to use that command, it displays as "gdb not found" in kshell, putty.

Comment: @suvitha: Neither `ksh` nor `PuTTY` are an operating system.

Comment: @suvitha: `uname -s` will usually tell you what Unix you are running. The system debugger may not be `gdb` (on Solaris it's...uhm...`dbx` I think).